# How to create a configuration with bot array and scalar prototypes

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection

I have the following configuration:

```
my_project:
    options:
        key1: value1
        key2: value2
        key3: value3
        key4: [sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4]
```

These options are not known by my extension, I would like to get an associative array:

```
array(
    "key1"=>"value1",
    "key"=>"value2",
    "key3"=>"value3",
    "key4"=>array("sub1","sub2","sub3","sub4") 
);
```

My tree looks like:

```
$rootNode
    ->addDefaultsIfNotSet()
    ->children()
        ->arrayNode('options')
            ->useAttributeAsKey('key')
            ->treatNullLike(array())
            ->prototype('scalar')->end()
        ->end()
    ->end();
```

The problem is that with the key/value "key4" I have an exception (this is normal as the prototype is 'array').

So my question is : How can I mix both scalar and array options?

Comment: don't forget the `,`: `key4: [sub1, sub2, sub3, sub4]`

Comment: i think you cannot validate a mixed array like that. but it will be loaded in the extension anyway so you can use it, just remove the configuration so you don't get an exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the help @lackovic!

Here is my solution:

```
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
{
    $processor     = new Processor();
    $configuration = new Configuration($this->getAlias());

    $options = array();
    if(isset($configs[0]['options']))
    {
        $options = $configs[0]['options'];
        unset($configs[0]['options']);
    }
    $config = $processor->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);


    // Now $options contains all the options and $config the configuration of my bundle
    ...
}
```

This solution help also to include sub-levels of configuration:

```
my_project:
    options:
        key1: value1
        key2: value2
        key3: value3
        key4: [value1, value2, value3, value4]
        key5: 123
        key6: 
            subkey1 : [value5, value6, value7]
```

That returns:

```
array
(
    "key1" => "value1"
    "key2" => "value2"
    "key3" => "value3"
    "key4" => array(
            0 => "value1"
            1 => "value2"
            2 => "value3"
            3 => "value4"
    )
    "key5" => 123
    "key6" => array(
        "value1" => array(
            0 => "value2"
            1 => "value3"
            2 => "value4"
        )
    )
)
```

)